# After taking photo buttons don't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem with my app. Here is my activity TakePhotoOrUpload

```
public class TakePhotoOrUpload extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button btnTakePhoto;
Button btnUploadPhoto;
Button btnViewPhotos;
Button btnLogout;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnTakePhoto) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TakePhoto.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnUploadPhoto) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadPhoto.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnViewPhotos) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewPhotos.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLogout) {

        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }




}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo_or_upload);

    btnTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto);
    btnUploadPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadPhoto);
    btnViewPhotos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewPhotos);
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnUploadPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnViewPhotos.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

}

and then when I click on TAKE PHOTO button then is this code open(TakePhoto activity)

```
public class TakePhoto extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;


private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo_or_upload);

    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout5);

    dispatchTakePictureIntent();

    try {

        createImageFile();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

}

my problem is, when I take photo and save it, it comes to activity with buttons(akePhotoOrUpload) but buttons unresponsive. I have to click back button on my phone then activity like refresh and everything work fine. Can you see the problem in code? Thanks.

Comment: Where/how you're starting `TakePhotoOrUpload` activity? And why you're using the same xml file ***activity_take_photo_or_upload*** for both activities?

Comment: Hi, TakePhotoOrUpload is started after I loggin. And i fixed using same xml(I was blind, sorry) but now where would you put code into TakePhoto java to start TakePhotoOrUpload activity? because for example when i put it into this try : try {

            createImageFile();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TakePhotoOrUpload.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
then when i click button TAKE PHOTO it just open again TakePhotoOrUpload activity.

Comment: While `TakePhotoOrUpload` activity is starting `TakePhoto`  one, you can just finishing `TakePhoto` activity to come back to `TakePhotoOrUpload` instead of starting it again.